# Нахождение суммы элементов массива в swift

Tags: swift, coredata

Имеется NSMutableArray в CoreData. Как сложить все элементы из этого массива?

Comment: надо узнать сколко элементов в массиве, или (предположу, что они там все цифры) подсчитать сумму значений? и надо ли делать fetch из coredata или это уже сделано?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko да это цифры, допустим fetch надо делать.

Comment: Либо без fetch. У меня сумму показывает всегда как 1, но там точно не 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну примерно так

```
let array: NSMutableArray = [1,1,2]
var sum:Int = 0

for(_, element) in array.enumerate() {
    sum += Int(element as! NSNumber)
}
print(sum)
```